suppress live rendering for latex in gitlab
I write a readme file using the md file gitlab provided me. I want to insert some equations in it, so I use LateX. I would like Latex to not be rendered while I am editing the file, but only when the file is published. Of course I could write it on a text file and then copy paste it, but anyway, I want to be able to do that.
Besides, the rendering is really terrible. I don't know if it comes from my browser, when I reload the file, once in a while, half of the TeX symbols are rendered properly, and usually it is closer to a quarter of them.
I tried to search in the settings, but could not find the disable live rendering option.

can you clarify where/how you're writing? By default, markdown is not rendered while editing, only after you save/commit the changes.

@Arty-chan Markdown is not live rendered, but LateX is or try to. If I put 2 dollars symbols and write something between them, the editor starts to do some really weird things. I would need a video for that. The text  moves, some parts written in pure text appear to be rendered in lateX, and you don't know where the typing bar is. In addition the final file doesn't handle the align environment correctly and I discovered you need a space between each dollar and the formulas for them to be accepted. The whole process is so tedious than even when you fo few mistakes, it's hard to check them.
